# uninitialized constant Heroku::VERSION (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, uninitialized-constant

Seemingly out of the blue, I am no longer able to run "rails server" or "rails console" on this project due to the above error message. I'm rather certain I ran a "gem update heroku" on this project's RVM gemset a few days ago, so that may be the root cause. Ruby is ruby-1.9.2-p136. Rails is Rails 3.0.9. Once I get to the bottom of this error, I plan on upgrading to the latest Rails 3.0 release (3.0.14), but need to resolve this issue first. Any ideas? I tried installing the Heroku toolbet to no avail.

The Heroku gem seems to be fine in all other ways, I am able to run "heroku login", "heroku rake", "heroku console", etc, just fine. The issue is only on my dev machine and only when I attempt to start up the server or run console. Next step is to clone this project on my new MacBook and move forward that way...

Comment: try `gem install heroku` again ?

Comment: to my knowledge the latest rails release is 3.2.6?

Comment: Perhaps find where you are using Heroku, and put an if Rails.env.production? to it. Your local server might not know what Heroku is

Comment: Start by doing a grep for Heroku::VERSION. Maybe something in your rakefile? Have you considered using [bundler?](http://gembundler.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading to the latest minor versions of Ruby (1.9.2) and Rails (3.0.14) resolved the issues. Thanks for all your help.